# Crediting a library

Tags: license-notice, bsd, closed-source

I'm using a library for a commercial application, and I'm wondering how I credit that library. The library is using the BSD-3-Clause license, and my application is going to be closed source.

Do I credit the library in the documentation of my application, and how?

Comment: Does the license itself not answer the question on accreditation?

Comment: The 3-clause BSD license requires producing a copyright notice, a set of redistribution conditions (which affect your application), and a disclaimer.  You can place all that in documentation (including help files) or in an "about" box for your app that mentions all the relevant copyright material. If you designed/implemented "your" app, you should know the libraries it uses directly. If you lifted code from someone else check the build script or documentation to work out what libraries it uses. Bear in mind some libraries use other libraries.

Comment: What about how could they find out if you actually use the library or not? It's hard to read the c++ code when compiled.

Comment: "How should I credit the library" is an on-topic question for this site, although as Peter has pointed out mostly covered by reading the license. "How would someone find out if I were using the library" is not on-topic here so I'll remove that bit from the question.